# Wrap Div in paragraph tag

Tags: html, css, alignment

The div within the paragraph tag does not wrap in the paragraph  tag. How do I achieve it to wrap? It floated into a new paragraph instead of being aligned within the `<p>` tag.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    #wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #leftcolumn,
    #rightcolumn {
      border: 1px solid white;
      float: left;
      min-height: 100%;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.94);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.94);
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.94);
    }
    
    #leftcolumn {
      width: 75%;
    }
    
    #rightcolumn {
      width: 25%px;
    }
    
    .inner-divs {
      height: 50px;
      width: 250px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.94);
      -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.94);
      box-shadow: -1px 1px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.94);
    }
    
    #img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    #div-embed {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background-color: #27d6bf;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div id="leftcolumn">

    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
      <p class="inner-divs">
        <div id="div-embed"><img id="img" src="C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\edit.jpg"></div>
      </p>
      <p class="inner-divs">
        <div id="div-embed"><img id="img" src="C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\garbage_delete.png"></div>
      </p>
      <p class="inner-divs">
        <div id="div-embed"><img id="img" src="C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\update.jpg"></div>
      </p>
      <p class="inner-divs">
        <div id="div-embed"><img id="img" src="C:\Users\ken4ward\Desktop\Tidy\zoom_icon.jpg"></div>
      </p>
    </div>
```

[image: Div not wrapping]

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` by default is a *block* element (as opposed to inline elements). The same goes for `<p>` elements.

If you want to wrap something inside a `<p>` element (or any other block element), use the `<span>` tag, which by default is an inline element.

BUT: You *can* change any elements appearance by defining another setting for it's `display` parameter:

```
.my_class { display: inline-block; }
```

will make the div with class "`.my_class` appear in one line with the surrounding content. The same goes for `display: inline`

For more details see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

P.S.: In your case you could probably simply leave the div tags out and just use the images as they are, inside the `<p>`tags. You can still style those with a CSS rule like

```
p.xxx1 img { bottom: 1px; height: 0.8 em; width: auto; }
```

in order to raise each image by one px and adjust it's size (`.xxx1`in this example would be the class that you include in the `<p>`tag.